# how to compile and include tensorflow lite in c++ file on wsl

Tags: c++, cmake, tensorflow-lite

I have a simple c++ file that reads in a custom trained model and an input array, I need to instantiate a tflite interpreter object to read the model array and do an inference. I've got my project directory which contains my source cpp code, CMakeLists.txt, build/ and tensorflow_src directory in which I cloned tensorflow. in my build directory I have been able to generate an executable that reads the model and the input, but I am unable to link my tensorflow lite library. This is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project(inference)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR "../tensorflow_src" CACHE PATH
  "Directory that contains the TensorFlow project" )

add_subdirectory(
    "${TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR}/tensorflow/lite"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tensorflow-lite" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

add_executable(inference inference.cpp model.cc)
target_link_libraries(inference tensorflow-lite)
```

I get various errors depending on how exactly I try to compile. For example:

```
CMake Error at tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark/CMakeLists.txt:87 (add_executable): Cannot find source file: tensorflow_src/tensorflow/tsl/util/stats_calculator.cc
```

I've tried extensions `.c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc`

I've checked that and that file is definitely there.

I just want the simplest possible way to instantiate a tflite interpreter and run an inference. Been working on it for days and have no idea where to get a simple answer.

I tried bazel, cmake, makefile. tried to build the minimal build provided by tensorflow but ofc it didn't compile. cmake works if I comment out the add_subdirectory and target_link_libraries.

Comment: _"I get various errors depending on how exactly I try to compile."_ [Please include those verbatim at your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76835103/edit).

Comment: I don't think any of them are useful. For example
```
CMake Error at tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark/CMakeLists.txt:87 (add_executable):
  Cannot find source file:

    tensorflow_src/tensorflow/tsl/util/stats_calculator.cc

  Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h
  .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc
```
I checked and that file is definitely there

Comment: _@luca_ _"I don't think any of them are useful."_ I strongly disagree. Let your audience decide. Generally it's **your** job to provide a [mcve], as required here for such questions.